# Compound data structure and fiddling with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, data-structures, stl

I'm trying to make a compound data structure class that consists of a quadtree and a simple STL vector since I want to be able to access data across the time horizon (i.e keeping the order in which the object is inserted). My initial implementation was to maintain a STL vector of `MyObject` and a `const MyObject * const` Quadtree.

Needless to say, I realized only a while after that in the moment that this compound data structure is deleted, there is no assuring that the quadtree is deleted first and the STL vector (which holds the underlying data) so possible memory issues may occur.

I was thinking of creating a `MyObject` instance on the heap when a new object is inserted and both quadtree and STL vector basically save the pointer to that (using `shared_ptr` or something?)

Any better suggestions?

EDIT: Here's my implementation thusfar. I think only the `insert` and `retrieve...` functions might be of interest

Header file:

```
#include "MapQuadTree.hpp"

typedef cv::Point2d Coordinate_t;

class PointsData
{
private:
    const unsigned int mMaxLevels = 10;
    const unsigned int mMaxPerLevel;

    unsigned int mMaxDataSize;
    unsigned int mCurrentIndex;

    std::vector<Coordinate_t> mPointsVector;
    MapQuadTree mPointsQuadtree;

public:
    PointsData(const unsigned int maxDataSize, double mapWidth, double mapHeight);
    ~PointsData();

    Coordinate_t operator[](int index);
    Coordinate_t last();
    Coordinate_t first();

    bool insert(const Coordinate_t& point);
    void retrieveNeighboringPoints(const Coordinate_t& point, std::vector<Coordinate_t>& neighbors);
};
```

Source file:

```
#include "PointsData.hpp"


PointsData::PointsData(const unsigned int maxDataSize, double mapWidth, double mapHeight)
: mMaxPerLevel(maxDataSize / mMaxLevels), mMaxDataSize(maxDataSize), mPointsVector(maxDataSize), mCurrentIndex(0),
mPointsQuadtree(0, maxDataSize / mMaxLevels, mMaxLevels, Coordinate_t(-1.0*mapWidth/2, -1.0*mapHeight/2), mapWidth, mapHeight)
{
}


PointsData::~PointsData()
{
}


Coordinate_t PointsData::operator[](int index)
{
    return mPointsVector[index];
}

Coordinate_t PointsData::last()
{
    return mPointsVector.back();
}

Coordinate_t PointsData::first()
{
    return mPointsVector.front();
}

bool PointsData::insert(const Coordinate_t& point)
{
    if (mCurrentIndex >= mMaxDataSize)
        return false;

    mPointsVector[mCurrentIndex] = point;
    mPointsQuadtree.insert(&mPointsVector[mCurrentIndex]);
    mCurrentIndex++;
    return true;
}

void PointsData::retrieveNeighboringPoints(const Coordinate_t& point, std::vector<Coordinate_t>& neighbors)
{
    std::vector<const Coordinate_t * const> results;
    mPointsQuadtree.retrieve(point, results);
    neighbors.clear();
    for (const Coordinate_t * const elemPtr : results) {
        neighbors.push_back(*elemPtr);
    }
}
```

Comment: _"Any better suggestions?"_ Hard to tell without having a concise sample. Are you sure you'll need a `shared_ptr`, or would a `unique_ptr` do as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the memory management should be delegated to your container. A possible suggestion should be the use of a smart pointer with your vector as this: 
`std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MyObject>>` if the memory holding your object will be shared or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyObject>>` if that memory will be not shared.

Comment: I eventually used a shared_ptr for both quadtree and `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MyObject>>` and created an object on the heap with `std::make_shared` every time an object was inserted. It worked perfectly fine and is much easier to manage

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a particular problem with your original design.

You will only have memory issues if you try to dereference a pointer in the quadtree after the vector has been destroyed. The actual order of destruction is not that important.

If the quadtree and vector are both managed by the same object they will be destroyed about the same time by the destructor of the managing object and all will be well.